# How to make it go to the main screen only when you allow notification access in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-notifications

I want the app to run like this:

When you run the app, you go to the window to set the notification access right, and if you go back while allowing access to the app, you go to the main screen. and when notification access right is not granted, you go to notification access window until right granted.

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val notificationManager =
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (!notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
                this.startActivity(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS))
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is written as above, but regardless of whether the notification permission is allowed or not, if you go back, you will be taken to the main page.

How can I modify my code so that I can navigate to the main page only when permission is granted?

Comment: This sounds, frankly, rather sketchy. If the user doesn't want your app spamming them with notifications, then it's your responsibility to accept that. Some permissions are essential for an app to run (for instance, a QR scanner is literally useless without the camera permission), but I can't think of a case where an app cannot do its job at all without notification permission.

Comment: I am making an app that reads the contents of a message using text-to-speech (TTS) when a messenger notification arrives.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [`READ_SMS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_SMS), or (if you're not talking about built-in Android messages but some other app) an intent specific to the messenger app you're targeting. The notification permission you're talking about is [`POST_NOTIFICATIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#POST_NOTIFICATIONS), which allows you to post new notifications, not to read existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in `MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
if (!isNotificationListenerEnabled(this, WhatsAppService::class.java)) {
            val enableNotificationListenerIntent = Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(enableNotificationListenerIntent)
        }    



private fun isNotificationListenerEnabled(context: Context, listenerService: Class<*>): Boolean {
        val flat = Settings.Secure.getString(
            context.contentResolver,
            "enabled_notification_listeners"
        )
        return flat?.contains(listenerService.name) == true
    }
```